# Python: simplemysql wrapper. Weird (no) Data transfer

Tags: sql, python-2.7, object, wrapper, nonetype

I need to say, that i actually learn programming and i try to solve this (propably) simple problem since hours. I want to check if a username already exists and if so, print a message, else write the Data for the new user into the DB. The script (check = db.getOne...) always returns "None" but read = db.getOne seems to read the Data. Where is the difference between them?

The query read = db.getOne("upers", ["logn"]) receives Data, but there is no Data saved in the DB. How can it be and how can i avoid the "None" problem and instead find the user? Sorry if my question seems crazy and like a spaghetti question, but im new to python (and stack overflow). Thanks in Advance for any Hints and Help!

The script:

```
import MySQLdb
from simplemysql import SimpleMysql
#Dokumentation: http://nadh.in/code/simplemysql/

db = SimpleMysql(
    host='localhost',
    user = '1234',
    db = 'name',
    passwd = '1234',
    keep_alive=True
)

def createu(u, p, m):
    username = u
    password = p
    mail = m
    check = db.getOne("upers",
    ["logn"],
    ("logn = %s", [username])
    )
    print check
    if check == None:
        db.insert("upers",
        {"logn": username, "pw": password, "mail": mail}
        )
        print "seems to work!"
    else:
        print "something is wrong!"
check = 0
u='test'
p = 'lol'
m = '123@lol.de'
createu(u, p, m)
read = db.getOne("upers", ["logn"])
print read
```

The Output:

```
None
seems to work!
Row(logn=u'test')
```

Also i cant imagine how the u finds its way into the output of the sql query.

I had many different approaches to get a simple database up and running and the simplesql wrapper seems to fit really good for a beginner like me, so i hope someone can point me in the right direction.

edit: It seems the data isn't even saved in the DB. When i log in to phpmyAdmin it cant find any data in the DB. But how can it be that i am able to read the Data with python? Magic?! oO

Another important question for me is: How can i extract the information from the print read result: Row(logn=u'test')